# Justify a function series is approximating another function.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here is a differential equation I read from text book today:

Solve
\[ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} y = y \] where $y(0)=1$.

The text book solves it like this, a\$sume \\( y = y(x) \\), it follows:
$$
y(x) = 1 +\int_0 ^x y(s) \;\mathrm{d}s
$$

Then the textbook constructs a function series: $y_0(x), y_1(x) \ldots y_n(x)$ to approximate \\( y(x) \\):

\begin{aligned}
y_0(x) &= 1  \\
y_1(x) &= 1 +\int_0 ^x y_0(s) \;\mathrm{d}s = 1+x \\
y_2(x) &= 1 +\int_0 ^x y_1(s) \;\mathrm{d}s = 1+x+ \frac{x^2}{2!} \\
\ldots \\
y_n(x) &= 1 +\int_0 ^x y_{n-1}(s) \;\mathrm{d}s = 1+x+ \frac{x^2}{2!} + \ldots + \frac{x^n}{n!}
\end{aligned}

I know $e^x$ is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n(x)$. So $e^x$ is a solution to this problem given $y_n(x)$ is approximating $y(x)$, but I cannot figure out why the constructed function $y_n(x) = 1 +\int_0 ^x y_{n-1}(s) \;\mathrm{d}s $ is indeed approximating to \\( y(x) \\). Any ideas?

Comment: @Moo It is $e^x = 1+x+ \frac{x^2}{2!} + \ldots + \frac{x^n}{n!}$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: OK, let me have a look, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Moo Great reference, I think I already get the point. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know $y=1+\int_0^x{y(s) ds}$, you cam replace $ y (s) $ in the integral from that relation.
$$y=1+∫_0^x{\left(1+∫_0^x \left(y\left(s\right) ds\right)\right)}dt=1+x+O\left(x^2\right)$$
$$
y=1+∫_0^x{1+∫_0^x \left(1+∫_0^x \left(y \left(s\right) ds\right)dt\right)da}=1+x+\frac 1 2x^2+O\left(x^3\right)
$$
And so on

Comment: I'm on a cell phone and can't get the mathjax to format correctly. If it can't be edited I will delete my answer. Edit: I think I fixed it

Comment: It looks great actually, you point makes a lot sense to me. I need some time to think about it to make sure I understand it completely.

Comment: yeah, I get the idea, thanks for your efforts for typing these on a phone :P